# Mask out python* in /usr/bin?

Tags: path

I'm on a school server where I can't sudo. Therefore, I've been installing software locally in my own folder.

Recently, I installed Anaconda's Python distributions and added Anaconda's `bin` folder to my `PATH`. When I `which python`, I can see it's my Anaconda's python -- as desired!

But I kinda feel this is really a mess, because the machine itself has many `python` executables in its `/usr/bin` too.

I can't just remove `/usr/bin` from my `PATH`, as there are other executables I need. So how can I "mask out" only `python*` executables from `/usr/bin`?

Comment: Why would you want to? They will never be used as long as your `bin` comes before the system directories. I don't understand what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @terdon For just `python`, that's right, my `bin` always comes before, but there might be other executables (say, `python-foo-bar`) is available in `/usr/bin` but not in my `bin`. I don't want to be able to call them and realize they are not my bin at the end of the day.

Comment: @terdon Also not sure why, but sometimes in my bash script where I did `python XXX`, I got `/usr/bin/python` running. I'm not sure why and want to debug that by removing `/usr/bin/python*` from my `PATH`

Comment: Well, the simplest solution is to never use `python` and instead always use `~/bin/python`. There is no simple way of excluding only specific names from the path, I'm afraid. You might be able to get some sort of complicated workaround but I really doubt it will be worth the effort. What would you want to happen if you run `python-foo-bar` and it isn't in your `~/bin`? Isn't it better to run the standard one? Maybe you could [edit] and clarify your use case a bit more?

Comment: I don't think that trying to bypass the system installation is a good idea. It will end in tears, as they say. If you want to do a local installation of python libraries, you can do so in your home directory, and configure python to see it. If that's what you want. Better, ask the admin to install them properly for you.